# How should one hyphenate this situation?

Tags: hyphens

> 1. The central bank interest rate is too high.

> 2. The central-bank interest rate is too high.

> 3. The central-bank interest-rate is too high.

Which of the above alternatives do you think is correct and why?

I feel that #3 is the correct one because "central-bank" is a compound adjective of the compound noun "interest-rate", and we should avoid misunderstandings (e.g. interpreting "central bank-interest-rate" where "central" is an adjective of the compound noun "bank-interest-rate").

I have never seen the usage of both hyphens as in #3 but I feel that this is the grammatically strictly correct usage, even if uncommon... Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions "central bank" and "interest rate" are well understood, and are not normally hyphenated. There is a theoretical ambiguity in the combined expression "central bank interest rate", since it could grammatically mean either the interest rate associated with the central bank (as it normally does), or the central interest rate associated with a bank. However the ambiguity is only theoretical. Since "central" is not normally used to compare numbers such as bank interest rates ("median" or "mean" might be used), the word is understood to refer to the bank and there is no ambiguity.

Your alternative 1. "The central bank interest rate is too high" is therefore correct

Comment: Thank you for your answer.